# Animation nodes texture value to vector

Tags: scale, conversion

I would like to scale multiple instanced objects based on a BW texture so i can get random scale on objects. Can i do it with textures or is there any other way?[image: the node so far][image: trying to randomize the scale of the hexes]

Comment: AN extra nodes version supports now textures